# Android Virtual Device gestures are broken/bugged

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, android-virtual-device

So I'm seeing some strange behavior only with the Android Virtual Device.  My app doesn't see this strange behavior on the Xamarin Android Player or a real physical Android device.  I've made videos demonstrating the buggy behavior and the correct behavior, see below.  I'd like to use the Android Virtual Device going forward, but I haven't been able to resolve these gesture issues that seem to be either a bug or a default setting or something.

[VIDEO: Bugged behavior with Google's Android Virtual Device](https://youtu.be/creIwEY3lBs)

- Notice I cannot unlock the app at all, it's almost like the device thinks my gestures starts in the wrong place.  At the end it worked when i swipped from the bottom left corner.  But no where else.
- Then notice I cannot single tap on my "..." button on the Flows screen.
- Only double tapping on the "..." button works.
- Then once that menu opens up, the Rename button is not tappable.  Almost as if it thinks the tap is going somewhere else.

  ---

[VIDEO: Correct behavior seen in Xamarin Android Player and on every Android physical device](https://youtu.be/tLQ7N2W6AXU)

- Notice I can unlock the app with ease.
- I can tap on the "..." with one single tap.
- I can tap the rename button just fine.

Comment: Does this happen on a newly created AVD image, and state which AVD image (x86 HAXM or ARM emulation) you are using.

Comment: So in Xamarin Studio it's called, Android_Accelerated_x86:5554 (API 23).  It seems like it came with the latest Xamarin Studio version. After Xamarin builds, it launches something called "qemu-system-i386" which then launches this Android Emulator.  I haven't created an AVD Image myself.

Comment: Try to edit the skin of the default Android emulator. I typically use pre-defined images like the Nexus 5/Nexus 6 to ensure they are easy to use. The Xamarin Android player is technically deprecated and thus you shouldn't use it for the future.

Comment: So I installed Android Studio and the AVD, but now I can't get Xamarin to run the those emulators.  It's saying "The emulator exited unexpectedly.  Please check the emulator settings"  So I'm trying to fix that....  Yeah I'd ditch the Xamarin Android Player, but it's actually working for me with Xamarin unlike AVD :-(